# TFS After branching, can the branch be updated

Tags: tfs, branching-and-merging

I created a branch of a project in TFS. The project continues to get updated. I worked on my branch for a couple weeks.

I am now finished working on my branch. However, I don't want to merge back just yet, nor can I take advantage of private builds.

I was wondering if there was a way to merge project changes to the branch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. From Visual Studio go to your Team Explorer (if you don't already have a tab for it, go to View > Team Explorer)
2. Source Control Explorer
3. Navigate to your branch in source control explorer. Right click on it
4. Find "Branching and Merging" in the context menu
5. Choose "Merge..." from the Branching and Merging selection
6. You'll be presented with the Source Control Merge Wizard that will ask you a Source branch and a Target Branch. The branch you created is the Target branch. The branch you branched from is the Source branch.
7. Usually choose "All changes up to a specific version" to get the latest changes from the source branch. Otherwise find the last changeset you're interested in and choose "Selected Changesets"
8. Choose "Next" in the wizard and go through to completion. You may have to manually resolve some conflicts